# loemlin with AWStune lamfgbhbda function

Tags: tinkerpop

Im trying to leamlin with AWS neptfdsune lambda in javascript.

the problem is i dont know how to import "has" & "both" in the above query? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: ** are just to highlight has and both here. i dont use them in actual query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an "anonymous" traversal (not connected to other steps by a dot) you need to prefix the step with `__.` (double under bar). So your query becomes:

```
g.V().
has("person", "first_name", fromName).
until(__.has("person", "first_name", toName)).
repeat(__.both("friends").simplePath() )
```

In case you need help finding the common imports for the Gremlin JavaScript client, some key ones are listed here: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-javascript-imports

Comment: thanks bro 
in my case i have to import it from gremlin.process.statistic.has

Comment: now thins query is working and returning me this :
[
  Path {
    labels: [ [], [], [], [] ],
    objects: [ [Vertex], [Vertex], [Vertex], [Vertex] ]
  }
]
do you know how to get the label in form of strings?

Comment: A `path` step can take `by` modulators that you can use to change what is returned for the elements of the Path. There are some examples here http://www.kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#pathintro

Comment: thank you sir im follwoing this link too great help.

Comment: sir i have another question related to this if u can answer plz.